# Get regkey based on search, then add new entry to that key

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search the HKLM hive for the key `driverdesc` that contains the value `-like "*Ethernet*"`

I can retrieve all the keys with `driverdesc`, however I cannot filter for the one containing Ethernet and then add the REG_DWORD *'PNPCapabilities'* to that key.

Here's how I am searching the registry:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | foreach {$_.GetValue("Driverdesc")} | Out-String $Items

$items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my function [Search-Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54062271/9898643) for this.

Search the registry like this:

```
Search-Registry -KeyPath 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}' -Pattern "*Ethernet*" -SearchPropertyValue -Recurse
```

This will return an array of objects with the following properties (example):

> ```
> ComputerName     : YOURMACHINE
> Hive             : LocalMachine
> HiveName         : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
> HiveShortName    : HKLM
> Path             : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0007
> SubKey           : SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\0007
> ItemType         : RegistryProperty
> DataType         : REG_SZ
> ValueKind        : String
> PropertyName     : DriverDesc
> PropertyValue    : Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
> PropertyValueRaw : Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
> ```

Using these properties (most likely `Path`) it should be easy enough to add a new DWord value. So in your case:

```
$value = 1234
$items = Search-Registry -KeyPath 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}' -Pattern "*Ethernet*" -SearchPropertyValue -Recurse -Verbose
$items | Where-Object { $_.PropertyName -eq 'DriverDesc' } | ForEach-Object {
    # New-ItemProperty either wants the shortpath notation 'HKLM:\path' 
    # or uses the 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\path' notation
    $path = $_.HiveShortName + ':\' + $_.SubKey
    New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'PNPCapabilities' -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force| Out-Null
}
```